# Can you remove a level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have several levels that only generate small amounts of money compared to others. Is there a way to get rid of them entirely?

Comment: Why would you want to remove them though? What purpose would this have?

Comment: @char1es In Tiny Tower you could demo a level and build it out as something else, saving some time.

Answer (score 9):

There does not appear to be any way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove a level, however you can upgrade the rank of the level which can increase  their profitability.